# project ':sign_in_with_apple' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17EOH.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV1sv.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXF5e.png)

I use the flutter_ui package. When I build it, I get an error. Please help me. Thank you

I use the flutter_ui package. When I build it, I get an error. Please help me. Thank you